# How can I use javascript to enable a "create account" button once all fields have correct input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

What I am trying to accomplish and have been unable to figure out after reading from different sources all day is, how do I get the disabled attribute from a button to go away once all of the fields have input? At this point in time it doesn't really matter what is in the fields as long as they have something. I have worked on a addEventListener which I tried doing a if(validateForm()) createBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');

```js
const form = document.getElementById('createForm')
// Selecting all text elements

const createBtn = document.getElementById('createBtn');



/*
    methods to validate user input
*/
// validate that all fields have input
function validateForm() {
    // get values from input
    const studentIdValue = studentID.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password_confirm.value.trim();
    
    
    if(studentIdValue !== "" && emailValue !== "" && usernameValue !== "" && firstnameValue !== '' && lastnameValue !== '' && passwordValue !== '' && password2Value !== ''){
        if(validateEmail(emailValue)) {
            createBtn.disabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        createBtn.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://github.com/claudewill1/Project/blob/main/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between p-1">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 nopadding">
        <form action="" id="createform" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <h2 class="form-title">Create a New Account</h2>
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->
          <!-- added ids to divs for input control to be able to access elements with script -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Student ID" autofocus type="text" name="studentid" id="studentId" value="">

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="email_div">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Email" autofocus type="text" name="email" value="">

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="username_div">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Username" autofocus type="text" name="username" value="">

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="firstname_div">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="First name" autofocus type="text" name="firstname" value="">

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="lastname_div">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Last name" autofocus type="text" name="lastname" value="">

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Password" autofocus type="password" name="phash1" id="pass1_div" value="">

              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-gold" type="button" id="show1" onclick="toggleInputType1()">
                SHOW
              </button>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Retype Password" autofocus type="password" name="phash2" id="pass2_div" value="">

              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-gold" type="button" id="show2" onclick="toggleInputType2()">
                SHOW
              </button>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

          <div class="form-group pt-3">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!-- changed id for create button to "createBtn" -->
              <button class="form-control rounded-0 btn-blue" type="button" id="createBtn" disabled onclick="btn_create()">
              Create Account
            </button>
            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
            <div class="input-group">
              <button class="form-control rounded-0 btn-gold" type="button" id="submit" onclick="btn_home()">
              Home
            </button>
            </div>
            <!-- input-group -->
          </div>
          <!-- form-group -->

        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- col-md -->

      <div class="col nopadding">
        <img class="side" src="./img/hero-image.jpg" alt="Hero Image">
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 -->

    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Also, please don't close my post as other have done in the past if I asked the question wrong, I am new for the most part to stackoverflow and I am posting based off the rules I see for posting. I made sure to only  If needed I can edit this.

Comment: I didn't read your code, so forgive me if this is way off, but hopefully this helps: Shouldn't you be able to add event listeners to all the input fields that you want to have content, and listen for the `input` listener... Then when any of them trigger the `input` event they should run a `checkIfAllFieldsAreFilled()` method, which checks all their `.input` values. If none of them `=== ""` then set something like `unblockSubmitButton()` and if one is blank then `blockSubmitButton()` - - - I really hope this helps!

Comment: Why don't you just create the button in advance, then have a `.hide` CSS class or something, then `Element.classList.remove('hide')` when you want to show the button. Of course you have to use an actual Event... there is no `createAccount` Event.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I will try both. This is one of those things once I get it figured out I won't have any issues with it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I modified your validateForm() function a little and added another function that monitors the form for change.

```js
function validateForm() {
    "use strict";

    //Check your HTML file. You'll need to add an id where there is none.
    const studentIdValue = document.getElementById("studentid").value.trim();
    const emailValue = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    const usernameValue = document.getElementById("username").value.trim();
    const firstnameValue = document.getElementById("firstname").value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = document.getElementById("lastname").value.trim();
    const passwordValue = document.getElementById("pass1_div").value.trim();
    const password2Value = document.getElementById("pass2_div").value.trim();

    if (studentIdValue !== "" && emailValue !== "" && usernameValue !== "" && firstnameValue !== "" && lastnameValue !== "" && passwordValue !== "" && password2Value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("create-btn").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}

//This function monitors the form for change.
function checkForm() {
    "use strict";

    const yourForm = document.getElementById("createform");

    yourForm.addEventListener("change", function () {
        validateForm();
    });
}

checkForm();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke `validateForm()` function on every input field update. You can do something like this with `onkeyup` event:

```
<input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Student ID" autofocus type="text" name="studentid" id="studentId" value="" onkeyup="validateForm()">
```

That way once all the validation criteria are met your button should become active.
As an option you can definitely use event listeners outside of your html for each input field instead to trigger the `validateForm()`.